# Group posts in category page by year from custom field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In a single category template (`category-realeses.php`) I would like to display all posts from this category grouped by year from custom field, because the post date is 2019 in almost all cases.

For example:

**2019**

-First post

-Second post

-Third Post

**2020**

-Fourth post

-Fifth post

-Sixth Post

Every single year contains a table from this 3 entries and 3 post thumbnails.

I am expecting, that this solution already exsists or a base, that I could edit, but after few hours of searching I gave up.